Transfer Issue with tsop-agent v3.0.5219: Update to v3.0.5235
We recently encountered a problem with our file transfer configuration using the tsop-agent for Google Cloud Storage. Here is a summary of the situation:
Problem Description

Observed Error:
E0621 13:52:09.606702 13863 handler.go:168] failed to initialize upload: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (10 attempts): Post "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o?alt=json&ifGenerationMatch=0&uploadType=resumable": dial tcp: lookup www.googleapis.com on DNS_IP:35 no such host

Scenario:



Launch an STS job to synchronize a POSIX filesystem on-prem to a GCP bucket.
The synchronization consistently fails since 06/20.

Environment

Environment: Production
GCP Service: Storage Transfer Service / Storage Service
DNS Configuration: DNS resolution for Google URLs (googleapis.com) is intentionally disabled by our security policies.
Proxy Configuration: All HTTP requests are routed through a proxy that can resolve and route these requests.

Diagnosis

DNS: No resolution for www.googleapis.com and google.com, as expected.
Proxy: Correctly configured, curl commands work via the proxy.
STS Logs: Transfers fail for files approximately 35 MB or larger.

Solution
After various tests and verifications, we discovered the problem stemmed from the version of the tsop-agent. An automatic update occurred, upgrading the agent from version v3.0.5219 to version v3.0.5235, which resolved the issue.
Question
Has anyone else experienced this problem with tsop-agent version v3.0.5219? Do you know what was fixed in version v3.0.5235 to resolve this issue? I searched the documentation but couldn't find the release notes to compare the two versions.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Additional Details for Context:

DNS Configuration: DNS resolution for Google URLs is intentionally disabled by our security policies.
Proxy Configuration: Verified and correct, with an initial warning about Boto configuration resolved.
File Size: Specific issue with files around 35 MB or larger.
Logs: Consistent error message on DNS resolution.

Thank you for your attention, and I hope someone can provide insights on the differences between these two versions of the tsop-agent.

As per the official GCP document on Troubleshoot file system transfers :

The agent version is no longer compatible with Storage Transfer Service.
This is a temporary error, related to a bad agent update. If it occurs, do the following:

Stop all of your agents.

Incase if you are using a docker, Pull the latest docker image by running: sudo docker pull gcr.io/cloud-ingest/tsop-agent

Issue the Docker run command to start all of your agent containers.


If the issue persists, reach out to the GCP support team by creating a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue.


Thank you I have seen this on the doc but you are missing the point the error I had is "failed to initialize upload" not "AGENT_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION"

The network subsystem removing OS rules might impact older systems. See this GitHub commit GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent for more details.

Hello kPranay no your answer did not help and you're still missing the point
